# In python, what is contained in the info property of a module object?

Tags: python

I'm looking into creating a Plugin structure for a program and making it so even the core library is treated as plugins. in my research I came across this code that is dynamically importing modules.

```
def __initialize_def(self, module):
    """Attempt to load the definition"""

    # Import works the same for py files and package modules so strip!
    if module.endswith(".py"):
        name = module [:-3]
    else:
        name = module

    # Do the actual import
    __import__(name)
    definition = sys.modules[name]

    # Add the definition only if the class is available
    if hasattr(definition, definition.info["class"]):
        self.definitions[definition.info["name"]] = definition
        logging.info("Loaded %s" % name)
```

I have tried to understand what this code is doing and I've succeeded to a point. However, I simply can't understand the latter part of the code, specifically these two lines:

```
if hasattr(definition, definition.info["class"]):
    self.definitions[definition.info["name"]] = definition
```

I can't figure out what `definition.info["<key>"]` is referring to.

What is this `.info[]` dictionary and what does it hold? Is it common to all Python objects or only module objects? What is it useful for?

Comment: Any particular reason why you use "definition" as a variable name instead of "module"?

Comment: this isn't my code. I found it while researching the concept. my guess is they used "definition" because they didn't want the possible confusion of using module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
py> import sys,os
py> sys.modules["os"].info["class"]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'info'
```

So this info attribute must be specific to modules that can be used as plugins in this program.

Comment: Oh wow, I wondered why I couldn't find any reference to it in the documentation of Python.  the generic way they named it made me think that the property was built in. cant believe that I didn't think to do the check you just posted there.

Answer (score 0):

Reserved names in Python generally begin with two underscores. You just stumbled on some piece of a larger codebase, that gives `info` module-scope values a special meaning. I don't think its authors chose a particularly good name for these, anyway; *$FRAMEWORK*_MODULE_INFO would be more explicit.